# Need a to a server to manage login and transfers of data from a ios app client to another

Tags: java, json, network-programming, ios6, client-server

I am making an ios app that will send data from on client to another.

Planning on using AFnetwork framework for the ios client app but now i need a server to be in the middle of the exchange of data that will also manage logins.

I did a little program in java to try make a connection between the ios app and the server but i think its to primitive and doesn't support the http protocol of the app.

Knowing that the java code is trivial and i will have to do other thing i will post both the java code and ios code so you guys have a idea of what i have so far.

I am looking for simple solutions for the server since i don't have very experience in that matter.

If you can give me simple server that manages to both receive from and send to.
Based on fact that i plan to use the ios AFnetwork i will apreciate it

thx in advance ;)

java code:

```
  class MobileTestServer
  {
  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
  {
     String clientSentence;
     String capitalizedSentence;
     ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
     System.out.println("Servidor");
     while(true)
     {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection received from " + connectionSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
     }
  }
```

}

ios code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dataToSend;
    [dataToSend setObject:password forKey:login];


    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:6789"]];


    NSMutableURLRequest *signInRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"http://localhost:6789/login" parameters:dataToSend];
    signInRequest.timeoutInterval = 15.0;
    signInRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

    AFJSONRequestOperation *signInOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:signInRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {
        NSLog(@"sent");
    }
                                                                                              failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
    {
        NSLog(@"not sent");
    }];

    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:signInOperation];
```